# Can i register/unregister broadcast receiver in onCreateView/onDestroyView respectively?

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

I am broadcasting data (file download complete) from `AsyncTask` to `Fragment` and updating `ListView` accordingly.

I have read that broadcast receiver should be registered/unregistered in `onStart()`/`onStop()` respectively.

But in this case i will miss data which has been broadcasted when app is not foreground but running in background (`onStop()` called but `onDestroyView()` not called) .

So to resolve this issue can I register/unregister broadcast receiver in `onCreateView()`/`onDestroyView()` respectively?

Also suggest if there is any alternative solution to this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it is common practice that broadcast receivers be registered in any method including `onCreate()` and be unregistered in any method including `onDestroy()`. Used in the `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods are really common practice. I also know of maybe the only other way to register a broadcast receiver and that is to register it in the Manifest. That basically means that as soon as the app is run for the first time the `broadcastReceiver` will always be running in the baground. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you KISHORE_ZE. Your answer helped me up to good extent. But will it throw runtime exception in any cases, if i unregister broadcast receiver in onDestroy()? What if user minimizes the app and then kills it from task list. In this case onDestroy() will not call, so will it throw any runtime exception? Thanks in advance

Comment: When the user kills it from the task list ondestroy is called and when minimized onPause is called this should therefore not cause any runtime error

Comment: What do you mean every time the app is killed not minimized onDestroy is called

Comment: Let me explain.                                      `onCreate` is called when the app is opened either for the first ever time or after if it got killed via task list.       `onPause` is called when the application is minimized or sent to the baground.                                        `onResume` is called whenever an app is maximised or brought to the front after being either minimized or being sent to the baground.                `onDestroy` is called whenever the app is killed via task list or any third party task manager or even if it is killed via restart/reboot as well. So no worry

Comment: I got your point but i have read some answers on this site, which states that there is no guarantee of onDestroy() being called, when app is removed from task list.

Comment: So in this case i wont be able to unregister broadcast receiver.

Comment: This is not true. Please do try searching. This always and **always** works for me of course when minimized it is not called however when killed it **is** called.